# NextJs 13 auto reload not working in some files

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a nextjs13 app properly setup with guidelines from the docs, Every file in every folder inside my src/app/ directory seems to be calling the auto/hot reload functionality properly whenever I make a change except in my Navbar component file which I am exporting from src/app/components/navbar and importing into the layout.js file of my app (the default root layout file).

Whenever I want to change something in the file I have to stop and start the server again with npm run dev to see those changes. This isn't the case for other files.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The issue was a dumb one, I was importing the component using

```
import Navbar from './components/navbar/NavBar';
```

When the file name was "Navbar.jsx".
This was somehow working with manual server restarting and not with auto reload.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my own 'solution' in the probably unlikely case somebody else runs into this rather newb kinda mistake (which I am).

After searching for the problem for two days, reinstalling Node.js, and changing versions up and down, I stumbled across this:

[Uncaught Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74515807/uncaught-error-invariant-expected-app-router-to-be-mounted)

And lo and behold, once I had implemented the  tag, everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue with Windows case incensitivity.

`productSearch` vs `ProductSearch` file name in my case.

No complaint on the import, but HMR just didn't work.

Check for filename correctness.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with essentially the same symptoms. In a component with a useEffect hook, no edits, whether to the hook or to any other part of the component, would cause the hook code to be rerun. Very confusing when one is used to Vite and how its hot module reloading works.

It turns out that the “fast refresh” feature in Next works differently and does not generally reload the entire component when something is edited. The following line can be added to the component file to change the behavior, so that every edit reloads the component completely:

```js
// @refresh reset
```

This is documented here: https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/fast-refresh