# console.log and alert not working in Next.js application

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I'm encountering an issue with my Next.js application where both console.log and alert are not behaving as expected. I've checked the code, browser settings, and environment, but I'm unable to pinpoint the problem. Here are the details:

I'm using console.log for debugging purposes. However, when I add console.log statements in my code, I don't see the expected output in the browser's developer console. Additionally, the alert function is not displaying pop-up alerts as it should.

Node.js Version: 18.17.1
Next.js Version: 13.5.4
typescript": ^5

Errors and Warnings in  from the browser's developer console: `invariant expected app router to be mounted`

Following is the code.(I simplified it to carry most relevant details )

`\mooneducationcenter\src\app\addteam\page.tsx`

`

```
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function AddTeam() {
  console.log("## This is console message ##");

  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const router = useRouter();

  const handleSubmit = async (e:any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!name) {
      alert("Name is required.");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/teams", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name }),
      });

      if (res.ok) {
        router.push("/");
      } else {
        throw new Error("Failed to create a team");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="flex flex-col gap-3">
      <input
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        value={name}
        className="border border-slate-500 px-8 py-2"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name"
      />
      
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="bg-green-600 font-bold text-white py-3 px-6 w-fit"
      >
        Add Member
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
`
```

I've tried a few troubleshooting steps, including rebuilding the application and testing in incognito mode, but the issue persists.

When I tried the same code file with another nextjs application in the same browser, the console.log and alert worked as I expected.

I suspect that the issue might be related to the project's configuration or dependencies.
Any assistance in identifying and resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The error `invariant expected app router to be mounted` seems to be addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74515807/uncaught-error-invariant-expected-app-router-to-be-mounted. See if that helps!

Comment: This solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

your code is working on my pc. when i try to click add member button it shows alert name is required and after adding the name it redirects me to new page. and it show console message when i change the model. you should try changing the browser.
as you can see in the picture at the center alert box, at the right side your console messages.
[image]

Comment: Thankyou! The issue was with my root layout. After adding the <html> and <body> tags to the root layout, it worked.